# Minko bullet sleep mode and constrains

Tags: c++11, bulletphysics, minko

Is there any way to enable an object sleep mode in minko with the bullet plugin?
I'm building an static tower of cubes and I want to demolish it throwing  balls.
Until now I just have a tower that falls every time it's build.

Somebody knows if there is a way to use bullet's constrains with minko?

All the code have is in the following git repository: https://github.com/fedemarino31/leaptower.git

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Bullet's constraints are not implemented. Feel free to provide a pull request.